# Cannot insert elements in a jQuery XML object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm using the new $.parseXML() method with jQuery 1.5 to parse a string into a valid XML object.  Once I convert the string to a jQuery XML object, I am able to navigate the DOM of the XML and look up values.  I can even change the values of different attributes.  However, I cannot insert new elements into the XML, even though I believe this is supposed to be possible.  Below is a code snippet that illustrates the issue:

```
var myXml = "<one attr='a'><two attr='b'/><three attr='c'><four attr='d'/></three></one>";
myXml = $.parseXML(myXml);
$(myXml).find('two').attr('attr','new value'); //<-- This works
alert($(myXml).find('two').attr('attr')); //<-- This works too
$(myXml).find('three').append('<five>some value</five>'); //<-- Does not work
alert($(myXml).find('five').text()) // <--Null
```

Does anyone have ideas on making this work?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that you're appending a string instead of a DOM element.  To append a DOM element you need to wrap the new XML in a `$(...)` expression

```
$(myXml).find('three').append($('<five>some value</five>'));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kDmD8/

Comment: I feel so foolish for overlooking that.  Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @jake don't feel foolish. Everyone makes mistakes. That's what stackoverflow is for ;)