# Add one xml element into another xml

Tags: javascript, xml

Please let me know how to do the following thing.

XML Document 1 :

```
<tag1 id="id1" name="myname">
      <tag_child1 child1id="child1"></tag_child1>
</tag1>
```

XML Document 2 :

```
<tag_child2>
    <tagchild2_child3 child_childid = "child_child3"> </tagchild2_child3>
</tag_child2>
```

Final Document :

```
<tag1 id="id1" name="myname">
      <tag_child1 child1id="child1"></tag_child1>

<!-- Document 2 -->
      <tag_child2>
            <tagchild2_child3 child_childid = "child_child3"> </tagchild2_child3>
      </tag_child2>
</tag1>
```

I tried using appendChild() function in javascript.But I wasn't able to do it. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code where you tried to append it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*pulls out glass ball...*

You have been trying

```
nodeFromDoc1.appendChild(nodeFromDoc2);
```

and the error said you cannot append child nodes that do not belong to a different document.

Try

```
var otherNode = doc1.importNode(nodeFromDoc2, true);
nodeFromDoc1.appendChild(otherNode);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.importNode

Comment: I am getting the following error...

"HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

What should I do in this case ?

Comment: Then you try to insert a node where a node cannot be inserted. Most probably you are trying to append a child to the root node. - There cannot be more than one element under the root node: *the document itself*. (Note that the *root node* is not the same as the *document element*.) Try to append your node to the [document element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement) instead.

Comment: My Bad... I didn't create XML DOM objects. Hence the error. After creating the DOM objects, I imported the the node and it worked perfectly... Thanks.. :)

Comment: Good to hear. Tip for next time: Always include a relevant (stripped down) code sample that demonstrates your problem. Leaving your fellow programmers in the dark, forcing them to guess exactly what you are doing is wasteful for both sides. Plus, future visitors who search for a problem will more likely find a solved question if you include code and exact error messages. (You can still do that and update your question at least with the error message, ideally with the wrong code, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I need more rep to comment. Are you using pure javascript or an api like jQuery? If so this answer may help.

[Cannot insert elements in a jQuery XML object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083571/cannot-insert-elements-in-a-jquery-xml-object)